# Marker line in rule-based layer?

Tags: qgis, rule-based

In a line layer, which is rule-based rendered :  As I can see it, it is only possible to ad simple lines.  I want to ad a marker line.  Is that not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add the rule then select the line type...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't see, that I should expand the window to see the button to select the symbol layer type

Comment: you are right, it looks like a bug. Even the "data defined override" buttons below disappear when the window is not wide enough